# Rails multi tenancy devise session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise, multi-tenant

I am developing multi-tenant rails app without using apartment gem. I have a problem with user authentication using devise.

When I sign up my user session is not shared across all subdomains.
I found that I need to change session configuration and here is how looks my config:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_hyggebulk_session', domain: 'lvh.me', tld_length: 2
```

here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }

  constraints(SubdomainRequired) do
    root to: "backend/dashboard#index", as: :authenticated_root
  end

  root to: "backend/dashboard#index"
end
```

I think that there is some little problem with my code, so please help me.

Comment: What is the "little problem?" What happens, versus what you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect my authenticate user is shared across all subdomain but for now devise session is not shared across subdomains

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the domains on which you want to share your session/cookie

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_hyggebulk_session', domain: '*.lvh.me', tld_length: 2
```

Or do something like:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_hyggebulk_session', domain: ['subdomain1.lvh.me', 'subdomain2.lvh.me'], tld_length: 2
```